# ZK error button action

Tags: java

I don't get a message in my web server.
I cant get the decimalbox's value when I click on a button.

the zk action (onClick$kalkulasi) didn't return anything

**this is my zk file**

```
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit"?>
<zk>
    <style>
    .silvergray .complex-layout,
    .silvergray .complex-layout .z-south,
    .silvergray .complex-layout .z-west {
        background: #C5E6EF; 
    } 
    .breeze .complex-layout,
    .breeze .complex-layout .z-south,
    .breeze .complex-layout .z-west {
        background: #F7F7F7; 
    } 
    </style>
    <style>
        .z-borderlayout { 
            background: #FFFFFF 
        } 
        .complex-layout .z-north { 
            background: #008BB6; 
        }
        img.complex-layout-header-img {
            padding: 0 10px; 
        } 
        .complex-layout-header-label { 
            position: relative; 
            top: -30px; 
            padding-left: 40px; 
            font-size: 24px; 
            color: White; 
            font-weight: bold; 
        } 
        .inner-border, 
        .inner-border .z-north, 
        .inner-border .z-west,
        .inner-border .z-south, 
        .inner-border .z-east { 
            background: #FFFFFF; 
        }
        .dl-link {
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
    <window id="win" title="Rasio Lancar" width="auto" height="auto" border="" apply="rasiolancar.lancarController">
        <borderlayout sclass="complex-layout" height="700px">
            <north size="90px" border="0">
                <div>
                    <image sclass="complex-layout-header-img" src="/images/Adempiere.png" />
                    <label sclass="complex-layout-header-label" value="SCM for Small and Medium Business" />
                </div>
            </north>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
            <west width="200px" border="0" flex="true" splittable="true" margins="0,5,0,0">
                <vlayout spacing="0">
                    <panel width="100%" border="normal" title="Menu">
                        <panelchildren style="padding:5px;">
                            <vbox>
                                <toolbarbutton label="Jurnal Keuangan" href="lap_keuangan.zul" image="images/book.png"/>
                                <toolbarbutton label="Buku Besar " href="neraca.zul" image="images/3.png"/>
                                <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Lancar" href="rasiolancar.zul" image="images/Modify.png" />
                                <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Kas" href="rasiokas.zul" image="images/2.png"/>
                                <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Cepat" href="rasiocepat.zul" image="images/Pie.png"/>
                                <toolbarbutton label="Rasio Modal Kerja dan Aktiva" href="rasioaktiva.zul" image="images/Bar.png"/>
                            </vbox>
                        </panelchildren>
                    </panel>

                </vlayout>
            </west>

        <!-- Content -->
            <center>
                <borderlayout sclass="inner-border">
                    <north border="0" height="4%" margins="2,3,0,0">
                        <label value="Rasio Lancar" style="font-size:20px;"  tooltip="jelas" />
                    </north>
                    <center border="2" margins="0,5,5,5">
                        <window>
                            <grid>
                                <rows>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <label>Bulan</label>
                                            <combobox id="bulan" >
                                                <comboitem label="Januari"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Februari"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Maret"/>
                                                <comboitem label="April"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Mei"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Juni"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Juli"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Agustus"/>
                                                <comboitem label="September"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Oktober"/>
                                                <comboitem label="November"/>
                                                <comboitem label="Desember"/>
                                            </combobox>
                                            <label>Tahun</label>
                                            <combobox id="tahun" >
                                                <comboitem label="2002"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2003"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2004"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2005"/>
                                                <comboitem label="2006"/>
                                            </combobox>
                                            <button id="kalkulasi1" label="kalkulasi1"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <label>Hasil</label>
                                            <textbox id="hasil1"  width="158px" />
                                        </div>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <hlayout>
                                            <label value="Perhitungan Manual" style="color:Black;font-size:20px"/>
                                        </hlayout>    
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <label value="Aktiva Lancar||"/>
                                            <label  value="Nilai Utang Lancar || "/>
                                        </div>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <decimalbox id="al" width="150px" />
                                            <decimalbox id="ul" width="150px" />
                                        </div>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <textbox id="hasil2" width="150px" />
                                        </div>     
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                        <div>
                                            <button id="kalkulasi" label="hitung"/>
                                            <button id="bersihkan" label="Bersihkan"/>
                                        </div>     
                                    </row>
                                </rows>
                            </grid>
                        </window> 
                    </center>
                </borderlayout>
            </center>
            <east title="Apa itu Rasio Cepat" size="30%" flex="true" collapsible="true">
                <div style="background:#cccccc">
                    <label value="Rasio ini berguna untuk mengetahui kemampuan suatu UKM dalam melunasi utang jangka pendeknya"
                        style="color:white;font-size:20px" />
                    <image src=""/>
                </div>
            </east>
            <south size="40px" border="0" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 ;">
                <toolbar mold="panel" align="center">
                            Powered by ZK 
                </toolbar>
            </south>
        </borderlayout>
    </window>
    <popup id="jelas" width="300px">
        <html><![CDATA[
           Rasio ini berguna untuk mengetahui kemampuan suatu UKM dalam melunasi utang jangka pendeknya
        ]]>
        </html>
    </popup>
</zk>
```

**and the controller file:**

```
    package rasiolancar;

    import controller.koneksi;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event;
    import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericForwardComposer;
    import org.zkoss.zul.Button;
    import org.zkoss.zul.Combobox;
    import org.zkoss.zul.Decimalbox;
    import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

    /**
     *
     * @author aulia
     */
    public class lancarController extends GenericForwardComposer {

        private Combobox bulan = null;
        private Combobox tahun = null;
        private Textbox hasil1;
        private Decimalbox al;
        private Decimalbox ul;
        private Textbox hasil2 = null;
        private koneksi k;
        private Connection conn;

        public lancarController() throws Exception {
        }

        public void onClick$kalkulasi1(Event e) throws Exception, SQLException {
            System.out.println("testststs");
            String bln = null;
            String thn = null;

            int b = bulan.getSelectedIndex();
            if (b == 0) {
                bln = "01";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "02";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "03";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "04";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "05";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "06";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "07";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "08";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "09";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "11";
            } else if (b == 1) {
                bln = "12";
            }
            int t = tahun.getSelectedIndex();
            if (t == 0) {
                thn = "2002";
            } else if (t == 1) {
                thn = "2003";
            }

//query ommited
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String sql = "select..from... where bulan='" + bln + "' and tahun='" + thn + "'";

    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Integer hs = new Integer(rs.getString(""));
            String h = hs.toString();
            hasil1.setText(h);


        }

        public void onClick$kalkulasi() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("test klik1");
            try {
                BigDecimal aktiva = al.getValue();
                BigDecimal utang = ul.getValue();

                //ngeprint
                System.out.println(aktiva);
                System.out.println(utang);

                int a = aktiva.intValueExact();
                int u = utang.intValueExact();

                int hs = (a / u) * 100;
                System.out.println("hasil integer" + hs);
                Integer h = new Integer(hs);
                String hsl = h.toString();
                System.out.println("hasil sebelum textbox" + hsl);
                hasil2.setText(hsl);
                System.out.println("hasil sesudah textbox" + hsl);

            } catch (Exception a) {
                a.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void onClick$bersihkan(Event e){
            al.setText(null);
            ul.setText(null);
            hasil2.setText(null);
        }
    }
```

Please help me guys, I guess the ZK file cannot read onClick action. but I'm not sure.

thanks for helping me :)

Comment: You seem to think everybody knows what "ZK" is supposed to be, yet this is not so.

Comment: Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "onClick$kalkulasi() return nothing"? That method's return type is "void".
Do you mean you cannot see "test klik1" printed on your console? Please describe your problem more clearly.